# Why is d3.histogram merging the last two bins of this chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, histogram

In this D3 chart I'm working on, I have a band scale containing 60 elements in a non-linear pattern (101-110; 201-210; 301-310; 401-410; 501-510 and 601-610 — the first digit represents the season and the last two digits represent the last two digits).

I'm able to render the chart perfectly fine, but the last bar gets merged into the one before it:

[image: busted histogram :sob:]

(Ignore the fact the x-axis labels are all messed up.)

Any idea why this is happening? Is it just because I've totally perverted the meaning of a histogram, or what?

Full example code [here](https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KgC9KpSnwOVNK0tGLHD).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct: you totally perverted the meaning of a histogram! This should be a bar chart instead.

Bar charts, by their very nature, are made of bars representing a **categorical variable**. It means that the bars are positioned over a label that represents a categorical variable, i.e., a qualitative variable. Both bar charts and histograms use rectangles to encode data, but in a histogram, unlike a bar chart, the label represents a **quantitative variable**. It's very common, if you search the web, finding "histograms" which are in fact bar charts, or "bar charts" which are in fact histograms.

Back to your question: It's possible to keep your histogram, in a hacky solution: you just have to define the [domain](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/master/README.md#histogram_domain):

> If domain is specified, sets the domain accessor to the specified function or array and returns this histogram generator.

So, your histogram generator should be something like this:

```
const histogram = d3.histogram()
    .value(d => d.death)
    .domain([0, 1000])//in your case: [101 or less, more than 610]
    .thresholds(x.domain());
```

(I'm using magic numbers here just to show the idea, change them accordingly)

And here is the updated code: https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KgCh8IjK6J56Dj_SA9X

#### Analysis

Apparently, `d3.histogram` is not creating the last bin when the value coincides with the threshold. According to the docs the last bin should be created, since `x1` (the top value for each bin) is not inclusive.

Let's see this snippet:

```js
var data = d3.range(10);

const histogram = d3.histogram()
  .value(d => d)
  .thresholds(data);

var bins = histogram(data);

console.log(bins)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
```

You can see that 8 and 9 were placed together in the last bin.

The same thing doesn't happen with the other thresholds. First, `thresholdFreedmanDiaconis`:

```js
var data = d3.range(100);

const histogram = d3.histogram()
  .value(d => d)
  .thresholds(d3.thresholdFreedmanDiaconis(data, d3.min(data), d3.max(data)));

var bins = histogram(data);

console.log(bins)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
```

Then, `thresholdScott`:

```js
var data = d3.range(100);

const histogram = d3.histogram()
  .value(d => d)
  .thresholds(d3.thresholdScott(data, d3.min(data), d3.max(data)));

var bins = histogram(data);

console.log(bins)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
```

Finally, `thresholdSturges`:

```js
var data = d3.range(100);

const histogram = d3.histogram()
  .value(d => d)
  .thresholds(d3.thresholdSturges(data, d3.min(data), d3.max(data)));

var bins = histogram(data);

console.log(bins)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
```

Comment: That updated example isn't working but I totally see what you're saying and that also totally works. Thank you very much, I've been tearing my hair out for ages about that! Any idea why it's exhibiting that behaviour? The same docs you linked to state that when undefined, domain is the `extent`; is it just the nature of the histogram generator that it's exclusive of the last (and possibly first) value?

Comment: It's funny, the updated example is working for me. I added some snippets to better explore this, have a look. Well, regarding your last question, I can't say if that is the desired behaviour or a bug. I believe you should open a GitHub issue, that way Bostock himself can explain what's happening here.

Comment: That's terrific, thanks for the very thorough exploration! Will open an issue!

Comment: No worries. Please, if you open an issue, paste the link here, I want to see Bostock's answer.